# How to account for embedded padding/margins of text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a look where two elements are touching vertically. The difficulty I am having is accounting for padding/margins that are embedded in the font. For instance, use your mouse to select a single word in this text. Notice the spacing above and below? Now to reference my difficulties, take a look at this image.

[image]

I want the text "WE CREATE" to sit on the block of cut-out text below. So the white is connected. How can this be done? I also need them to stay connected through scaling.

Here is my code, some of the stylings are done in other files, but that shouldn't matter unless you were trying to run it.

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="page-header header-filter clear-filter header-image md-layout">
            <h1 class="heading" >WE CREATE</h1>
            <div class="cut-text">EXPERIENCES</div>
            <h2 class="subheading">THAT TELL YOUR STORY</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
        }
    }

}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.header-image{
    background-image: url("../assets/img/bg12.jpg");
}
.cut-text {
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px !important;
color: black;
font-size: 10vw; /* Responsive font size */
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0 auto; /* Center the text container */
padding: 6vw;
width: 75vw;
text-align: center; /* Center text */
mix-blend-mode: screen; /* This makes the cutout text possible */
}
.heading {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 5vw; /* Responsive font size */
    margin-block-start: 0em !important;
    margin-block-end: 0em !important;
}
.subheading {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3vw; /* Responsive font size */
}

.md-layout {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why vue.js though?

Comment: @ishidex2 The webpage was built using Vue,js. I didn't share the code but if I needed to I wanted the right audience. I'll add my code.

Comment: yeah, but the question isn't related to `vue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to decrease the `line-height` css property of the text until you reach the correct text height.

Comment: Will give it a shot, thanks! But how will that change with the scaling of the text?

Comment: I tried to make the line height be equal to 5vw (matching the text height) but there is still spacing.

Comment: Can you edit your code with your try? This way I can try to do a snippet.

Comment: You were right, and for me a line height of 3.4vw seems to work perfectly! I will accept the answer once it lets me. Says I need to wait 6 minutes.

Comment: No problem, I hope this helps you.

Comment: Did you still want me to edit my code? It works now with a line height of 3.4vw.

Comment: It's not necessary any more if it's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that most of fonts make these gaps for capital or letters like 'p', so you can't just do it automatically

The solution is to set `line-height` to zero and manually set margin property, in my case it was `2vw`, here's the example

```css
body
{
   font-family: sans-serif;
   display: flex;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.block
{
   flex: 1;
}
.first
{
   background: black;
   color: #fff;
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-end;
   font-size: 3vw;
   line-height: 0;
   
   justify-content: center;
}
.first h1
{
  margin: 2vw;
}
.second
{
   font-size: 5vw;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block first">
   <h1>Sample text</h1>
</div>
<div class="block second">
   <h1>Sample Text</h1>
</div>
```